# 403 forbidden error on authentication filter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, websecurity

I am working on a basic spring boot api using mysql as database
I created an endpoint for signup user("/users") which is bcrypt the password
while login i created a authentication filter which is adding jwt token in the header of response
but while accesing endpoint ("/login") i am getting 403 error,
I have already configured the ant match for request named "/login"

**Web Security Configuration **

```
package com.mukul.app.mobileappws.security;

import com.mukul.app.mobileappws.security.FIlter.AuthenticationFilter;
import com.mukul.app.mobileappws.services.UserService;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;

import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ConfigurationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    UserService userService;
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bcrypt;

    ConfigurationSecurity(UserService u, BCryptPasswordEncoder b) {
        this.userService = u;
        this.bcrypt = b;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,
        // "/users").permitAll().anyRequest()
        // .authenticated();
        //
        AuthenticationFilter af = new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager());
       
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,
                "/users").permitAll();

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
        http.addFilter(af);

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(bcrypt);
    }

}
```

**Authentication filter**

```
package com.mukul.app.mobileappws.security.FIlter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.mukul.app.mobileappws.security.SecurityConstants;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;

public class AuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private AuthenticationManager authManager;

    public AuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager am) {
        this.authManager = am;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        final String email = request.getParameter("email");
        final String password = request.getParameter("password");

        return authManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, password));
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
            Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {

        // generate token
        User u = (User) auth.getPrincipal();
        String email = u.getUsername();
        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(email)
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + SecurityConstants.EXPIRE))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SecurityConstants.SECRET)
                .compact();
        response.addHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER, SecurityConstants.PREFIX + token);

        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, auth);
    }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhW2a.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your configuration is okay.

`http.addFilter(authFilter)` will put filter at appropriate position by examining the filter type.

In your case, I suspect issue is not triggering login request properly. As per the content in given repo, I ran the project and used embedded H2 instead of full blown database.

[image: Postman Trigger request]

This is how you need to trigger your request if you are reading from `request.getParameter(parameterName)`. Please note that I have received 404 error because Spring is trying to redirect me to '/' post successful login which doesn't exist. :)

Comment: But its not about filter running or not the ant match for login itself is not running. It's private

Comment: I am sorry. I did not understand. What do you mean by matcher not running ?

Comment: Matcher mean as i configured the http to make public endpoint as /users same i did for /login. /Users is working fine but /login is private and forbidden

Comment: http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,
                "/users").permitAll();

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll();

Comment: Can you run this app with debug =true ? And capture the filter chain once ?

Comment: Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  AuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]

Comment: my filter name is authenticationFilter and that is running but /login is private(forbidden)

Comment: Can you create a sample github repo so that I can take a look ?

Comment: How are you testing it ? You are not sending a JSON payload right ? Because request.getParameter() does not reads JSON request payload.

Comment: i was learning spring boot for the first time so i was trying , and about json payload i tried to convert using object mapper readvalue but got error so just to try used get parameter, I am sending json but

Comment: Okay. You have to raise request via query parameter or form values, not JSON. I still will insist that you create a GitHub repo for me to take a look. :)

Comment: creating github repo

Comment: https://github.com/bhutianimukul/spring-boot-learn

Comment: @MukulBhutiani: I have updated my answer. If it answers and solves your question, please consider accepting this answer by clicking on tick mark :).

Answer (score 0):

With Spring Security I always had problem with CSRF on login, because the page doesn't have the CSRF token and POST is not allowed without it, try to check with it.

Comment: He has csrf disabled already.